# Hard Reflections

Tags: reflection, npr

I've been doing a study about NPR and I am struggling with adjusting the reflections of the train's windshield based on the reference I'm trying to copy. Is there any way to get hard reflections of an object to a glass?

this is the reference photo I'm trying to copy. As you can see the train's windshield have a stronger contrast of the overhead pole's reflection.[image]

on the other hand, this is my recreation. On this one, the train's windshield only managed to get a slight tint of the overhead pole's reflection.[image]

Comment: If you want sharper reflections, you can just reduce the roughness?

Comment: it's already set to 0 since it is glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This windshield is likely made of tinted glass.  Tinted glass has higher reflectivity than clear glass to block out heat.

You can simulate this by mixing a *Glossy BSDF* into your shader.  Lowering the *Color* to some gray value will tint the glass, and the *Mix Shader Factor* controls how much visibility you have through the glass.  I.E. Full glossy would represent a two-way mirror.

[image]

Edit:  Don't forget to apply some thickness to your glass. :)

[image]